# Where is the source code for godoc itself?

Tags: go, godoc

I want to look at the source code for the `godoc` tool, but I cannot find it. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golang and its tools are also available on github now, https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/godoc